# Trying to make a grunt project working

Tags: sass, gruntjs, npm, zurb-foundation

I'm super noob to grunt I'm ready to start with this filed, but I'm stuck in a step. I've learn what it is and what is good for I've followed this quick start to make it working on my machine

https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress

Everything as worked fine until the line:

```
npm install && bower install && grunt build
```

Here below the errors i get:

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/to3ky/.npm/_locks/node-sass-f213edefcf6a8ef5.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /Users/to3ky/.npm/_locks/node-sass-f213edefcf6a8ef5.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/to3ky/.npm/_locks/node-sass-f213edefcf6a8ef5.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/to3ky/.npm/_locks/node-sass-f213edefcf6a8ef5.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aaa/studiohaupt/wp-content/themes/atheme2/node_modules/node-sass, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aaa/studiohaupt/wp-content/themes/atheme2/npm-debug.log
```

But I don't know what it mean.
I'm new to grunt bower npm so I's hard at this step to diving into it by myself.

If i run `grunt` i get

```
Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

I'm on a MAC and I use XAMPP, and I'm diving into darkness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fix your problem:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I think it has work fine for bower but for grunt now I get:
[http://pastebin.com/8CmqE6RM]

Comment: What version of node and npm do you have? "node -v" and "npm -v"

Comment: Node v0.12.0, Npm 2.5.1

Comment: You should install "n": https://github.com/tj/n . And then downgrade to node 0.10.x (for example 0.10.33). Probably your node version has problems with node-sass.

Comment: Done and it has worked better, even if it wasn't enough. I did all the commands preceded by SUDO at finally everythings is gone fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on OSX you should add `SUDO` before all your command line's commands.

Comment: You should definitely not do that.